# How to schedule a task to be run after a certain number of days

Tags: c#

I need to run a task after a certain number of days, such person while A (buyer) send a complaint to person B (seller) for product in poor condition, if within 30 days Person B does not respond then the money is returned to person A. I am using asp.net mvc, C # web services. implementation some suggestion please..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this may just be via a scheduled task.

Write your code as a headless command line executable, have it scheduled to run at 9am every day, and have it email someone a report for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use some database (it might be local SQL Express for example) to store such information and periodically iterate through it with help of database job or your application. You can store information like `TaskEndTime` and if current time exceeds it, call some web service that will take care of it.

This solution will let you persist information if application pool, IIS or even whole machine restarts, as it is very important to make this process reliable.